# How to specialize template template parameter for a class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class

```
template <class T>
struct TypeText {
    static const char *text;
};
```

and a couple of specializations for the "text" member:

```
template <> const char* TypeText<int>::text = "INT";
template <> const char* TypeText<long>::text = "LONG";
```

How to implement a specialization for `std::vector<A,B>` with no prior knowledge about `A` and `B` ? Is it possible to differ `std::vector<A,B>` from `SomeOtherClass<A,B>`?

The following doesn't work:

```
template <>
template <class T, class A>
const char* TypeText< std::vector<T,A> >::text = "vector";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could provide a [partial template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) for `std::vector`:

```
template <class T>
struct TypeText<std::vector<T>> {
    static const char *text;
};
template <class T>
const char* TypeText<std::vector<T>>::text = "vector";
```

then use it such as:

```
...TypeText<std::vector<int>>::text...    // "vector"
...TypeText<std::vector<long>>::text...   // "vector"
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/NNUOD71265)

Comment: You have changed the initial template class.

Comment: I am wrong. That is the partial specialization surprised me. Thank you.

Comment: @pavelkolodin BTW: Why do you want to specify the 2nd template parameter of `std::vector`? If you really need to do this, you can add the 2nd template parameter for the partial specialization too.

Comment: Can I not provide the TypeText<std::vector<T>>::text specializations for each type? I mean int, long... etc and use the default 
template <class T>
const char* TypeText<std::vector<T>>::text = "vector";